# Which Android Emulator to use for the Redmi Note?

Tags: android, mobile, android-emulator, simulator

I have a bug for the Xiaomi [Redmi Note](http://www.mi.com/en/redminote) 4x 64GB. I want to try to duplicate it in the Android Emulator.

Which Android Emulator should I use for the Redmi Note?

Thanks

Comment: I think there's a small language barrier. Please forgive me for asking... Are you asking which [Android Emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html) you should use for the [Redmi Note](http://www.mi.com/en/redminote)?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: @24sharon have you found any emulator finally? I need to reproduce the bug on redmi note 4x too..